# Start an animation nodes TimeCode Generator at a specific point

Tags: animation-nodes

Does anyone know how I would START a timer at a specific point?  I will need to use the timer between many scenes, and I need it to pick up where the previous scene left off....

Here's what my timer looks like:[image]

It is in days:hours:seconds:milliseconds format. In the next shot, I would need it to START at 00:00:03:15.  Here is the uber-simplistic node setup:
[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `n` to the time will offset the time `n` number of frames:

[image: Example 1]

Comment: thank you Omar!  Just getting started with animation nodes!  Thanks so much!